# Pandas - calculate percent of total given ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like get a percentage of the occurrences of speed data falling into a range as a percentage. As an example, 5% of the speed data is between 0 and 5, 10% is between 5 and 10, etc. I'd also like the ability to resample the output into any frequency (entire period, daily, monthly, etc)

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': '1234',
                   'datetime': pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq='H'),
                   'speed': np.random.randint(0, 5000, df.shape[0])})
df['speed'] = df['speed'] / 100.0

speedintervals = [0,3,5,9,15,21]
frequency = 'D' # for daily aggregation of data
# or frequency = 'P' for entire period
```

DataFrame looks like this:

```
    datetime             id     speed
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00 1234    17.08
1   2017-01-01 01:00:00 1234    16.30
2   2017-01-01 02:00:00 1234    12.74
3   2017-01-01 03:00:00 1234    39.89
4   2017-01-01 04:00:00 1234    34.33
5   2017-01-01 05:00:00 1234    22.76
6   2017-01-01 06:00:00 1234    13.72
...
```

I'm imagining that I'd set datetime to index and do a resample of sorts, but not sure how to build out the data.  Ultimately, I want the data to look like this:

For entire period:

```
id      start_date      end_date    0<=3    3<=9    9<=15   15<=21  >21
1234    1/1/17 0:00 1/1/18 23:00    0.49    0.13    0.18    0.17    0.00
```

For daily frequency:

```
id      periodEnd   0<=3    3<=9    9<=15   15<=21  >21
1234    1/1/18  0.49    0.13    0.18    0.17    0.00
1234    1/2/18  0.50    0.14    0.17    0.16    0.00
1234    1/3/18  0.25    0.10    0.25    0.25    0.15
...
```

any thoughts?

Comment: in the example you have provided, how come there is 0% for >21. Is that just a sample of what it needs to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one way to do it.

```
speedintervals = [0,3,5,9,15,21,100]
df["interval"] = pd.cut(df["speed"],bins=speedintervals)
result = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="datetime",freq="D"),"interval"])["interval"].count()
          .unstack(0).T.fillna(0)
          )
```

- add 100 to your list to capture the high speeds.
- Then use the cut method to group the speeds into intervals
- Group by the datetime and then the interval and then count
- This creates a multindex so you have to unstack it do get    the
  format you want.

You could use a pivot table instead of a groupby, but it's better to use group for dates.

If you want the normalized result you can do

```
result.div(result.sum(axis=1),axis="rows")
```

For the whole time period

```
pd.cut(df["speed"],bins=speedintervals).value_counts()
```

Comment: Wow.. amazing.  Looks like I'm really close here.. much better than my spaghetti code. How would you do the same thing for the whole period, rather than grouping by the standard frequencies?

Comment: I added a way to do that. But I mean you could just change the frequency to something large like yearly. That would do the trick as long as the frequency is larger than the gap in dates.

Comment: Looking great so far! for the whole time period, I added:
result = pd.DataFrame(result).transpose().reset_index(drop=True)

getting it into a DF allowed me to concat with the static data of the original to format it correctly